# Cannot Setup Debugging Environment for Php using Eclipse and XDebug on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, eclipse, ubuntu, xdebug, test-environments

I am following this [guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug) to setup a debugging environment for my PHP application. I am using eclipse and xdebug. I have done all the things that the guide has asked me to do. But when I put the breakpoints and run the application, the IDE doesn't stop. I know I am not being clear. But I don't know what else to say.

You can ask me questions and then maybe I will be able to explain my problem a little bit better. Thanks in advance.